# Can you vary text size within the same ggplot2 axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use ggplot2 to make a plot where the axis text size varies between labels- for example, larger font every five ticks with smaller font for the intervening ticks. I looked at using `minor_breaks` in `scale_x_continuous`, but I couldn't find a way to label the minor breaks.

The best I've got to work so far is a modification from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523862/5593066) where I use `bquote` to pass an expression for the axis labels:

```
label_span <- 1:40

ShrinkIf <- Vectorize(function(val) {
  if (val %% 5 == 0) return(as.character(val))
  return(bquote(scriptstyle(.(as.character(val)))))
})

x_labels <- ShrinkIf(label_span)

x_labels <- purrr::invoke(expression, x_labels)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg , y = hp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = label_span, labels = x_labels)
```

[image]

Is there a better way to go about this, or maybe a way with a little more control of the label size (or even font choice / text decoration, etc)? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a vector of text sizes and add it using `element_text()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = rep(c(12,24), 3))
    )
```

[image: example]

Comment: Clean and simple, that'll do it. Thanks!